# Languages/scripts supported by Alphabet[]

Tags: functions, text, natural-language

How can I get the full list of languages/scripts/alphabets supported by the [`Alphabet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html) function?

Note that while the auto-completion suggests many possibilities, it misses some, e.g. `"Gujarati"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I *think* this should be it.

```
Grid@Partition[
 CanonicalName@Keys[
  DeleteMissing[EntityValue[EntityList["Language"],"Alphabet", "EntityAssociation"]]],5]

(* Esperanto    French  Rwanda  Bulgarian   Cherokee
Lu  Afrikaans   Albanian    AlbanianArbereshe   Amharic
Arabic  ArabicStandard  Armenian    Assamese    Asturian
Azerbaijani Bamanankan  Basque  Belarusan   Bemba
BicolanoCentral Bodo    Bosnian Breton  Burmese
Catalan CatalanValencianBalear  Cebuano Chamorro    Cornish
Corsican    Croatian    Czech   DagaareSouthern Dagbani
Danish  Duala   Dutch   Dzongkha    English
Estonian    Ewe Ewondo  Faroese Fijian
Filipino    Finnish FrisianWestern  Friulian    Gagauz
Galician    Ganda   Garifuna    Georgian    German
Gikuyu  Greek   Gujarati    Hawaiian    Hebrew
Hiligaynon  Hindi   Hungarian   Icelandic   Igbo
Ilocano Indonesian  Interlingua InuktitutGreenlandic    IrishGaelic
Italian Kabuverdianu    Kabyle  Kannada Karakalpak
Kashubian   Kazakh  Kirghiz Kolsch  Konkani
Korean  Krio    Kurdish Ladin   Lakota
Latin   Latvian Lingala Lithuanian  Luxembourgeois
Macedonian  Malagasy    Malay   Maltese Manx
Maori   Mapudungun  Marshallese Mbundu  Mende
Micmac  Miskito Mohawk  Mongolian   Morisyen
Ndebele NorwegianBokmal NorwegianNynorsk    Nyanja  Nzema
Oromo   OromoWestCentral    Osetin  Palauan Pampangan
PanjabiEastern  Persian Pohnpeian   Polish  Portuguese
Romani  Romanian    RomanianMacedo  Romansch    Rundi
Russian SaamiInari  SaamiNorth  Samoan  Sardinian
Scots   ScottishGaelic  Serbian SererSine   SeselwaCreoleFrench
Sicilian    Slovak  Slovenian   SorbianLower    SorbianUpper
Spanish Swahili Swedish Tachelhit   Tahitian
Tetun   Themne  Tibetan TokPisin    Tongan
Turkish Turkmen Ukrainian   Urdu    Uyghur
UzbekNorthern   UzbekSouthern   Vietnamese  Walloon Waray
Welsh   Wolof   Yakut   Yoruba  Zarma *)
```

Comment: I think this could be done faster using an implicit entity class, e.g.: `EntityClass["Language", {"Alphabet" -> MatchQ@Except@Missing["NotAvailable"] }]`

Comment: Also no need for the *think* as `Alphabet` just calls Alpha internally. See ``System`CharacterFunctionsDump`getLanguageAlphabet``.